# scikit-learn normalize implementation in Java?

Tags: java, python, scikit-learn, normalization

I want to do vector normalization in java. Is there any implementation as [sklearn.preprocessing.normalize](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.normalize.html). I found a science [lib](http://dst.lbl.gov/ACSSoftware/colt/) in java, but there is no function for normalize like scikit-learn in python. Do you know any implementation in Java? Thanks for your info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found [one](https://github.com/MKLab-ITI/multimedia-indexing/blob/master/src/main/java/gr/iti/mklab/visual/utilities/Normalization.java) does the same thing as scikit-learn. There is L2Norm, L1Norm, SSRNorm implementation, it's such a long time that did not use statistics.....